# Perl: Dereferencing a hash ref into a scalar?

Tags: perl, hash, dereference

Why does dereferencing a hash reference into hash & assigning it to a scalar gives an irrelevant value (at least to me)?

Code:

```
my $hash = {
        1 => 9,
        2 => 10,
        3 => 11,
        4 => 12,
        5 => 13,
        6 => 14,
        7 => 15,
        8 => 16,
       };

my $dereferenced = %$hash;

print $dereferenced;
```

Perl version : 5.12.4

OS : Windows 7

The value printed is

```
7/16
```

Whether it has something to do with Perl internals?

Comment: What would you expect `$dereferenced` to contain?

Comment: my $dereferenced = %$hash; <- here you want to do %dereferenced with the % sigil, or \%$hash thus passing a reference

Comment: Thanks! Sorry that I posted the duplicate question! Now I understood that the total Bucket size = 16. The number of Buckets that contain one or more elements = 7. Hence 7/16. This hash had more collisions itseems!

Comment: @Borodin: I had thought in a different direction as follows.  we can define a hash as %hash=(1,2,3,4). it actually means (1=>2, 3=>4). In the same way, dereferencing a hash reference should also return the same kind of array (if the LValue is not a Hash). in this case (1, 9, 2, 10, 3, 11 etc). So assigning this returned array to a scalar will be as same as calculating the array length ($length = @array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalars cannot contain hashes or arrays, only references to them.

But even if they could, when you use a hash on the right side of a scalar assignment, it is in ***scalar context***, and a hash in scalar context produces false if the hash is empty, or a string describing the bucket usage within the hash if not (e.g. "7/32").

Comment: Eventhough, i have worked on perl for quite sometime, I didn't know how the hashing concept in perl works. Good to know the new term called 'Bucket'. thanks!

Comment: @InnovWelt the term *Bucket* is not very helpful for becoming a better Perl programmer whereas knowing the meaning of ***scalar context*** is.